# How to incorporate ViewPager into Stack Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to navigate from one page of a book to another without the use of a button, and ideally would like it to look like `turn.js` in *iBooks* and apparently I can get that through *ViewPager* but not sure how to implement it into my code.

**My code for my Navigator below:**

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import pageOne from '../screens/pageOne';
import pageTwo from '../screens/pageTwo';


const defaultNavOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

const PageNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    PageOne: pageOne,
    PageTwo: pageTwo  
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavOptions
});

export default createAppContainer(PageNavigator);
```

Comment: can I just ask why there are <br/> tags at the end of every line but your export at the bottom?

Comment: Hey bturner, that was just for formatting to show my code on here as in the preview my code wasn't wrapping onto the next line, please ignore the line breaks and view the code as if they are not there, thanks

Comment: Removed line breaks